# Tensorflow concat ValueErrror

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to concat 2 tensors both of type `float64`.

`tf.concat(predictions[:,:5], max_ind)`

However I get an error

`ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with dtype float64: <tf.Tensor: id=44, shape=(4800,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.])>`

I don't understand since the tensors are both `float64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.concat` expects `values` to concatenate and `axis` on which to apply the operation. As far as I understand from the error, the model thinks `max_ind` provided by you is the `axis`, and that is why it gives you an error saying that the axis should not be a float but an integer. If you are trying to concatenate `predictions[:,:5]` and `max_ind`, you should use it as follows:

```
tf.concat([predictions[:,:5], max_ind], -1)
```

I have used -1 as the axis, but you adjust it as you need.